# How to navigate to a specific Route at app start and show another one when popping in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, routes, navigation, navigator

The question is, how to achieve this with a clean navigation approach in Flutter.
So to better understand the question, here's an example:

*The user taps on a messenger notification and the app opens. The first screen to show is a setup screen, which verifies if the user authenticated and does some app related stuff. The next screen should be the chat with the corresponding message. After closing this chat screen, the user lands on the screen containing a list with all chats. After closing this one, the user lands on the home screen of the app.*

What is the best and cleanest approach to handle such a scenario? Should I use a separate navigation package like auto_route or what do u suggest?
Or is this a deep link scenario? How to implement such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Define static String id for all screen,after define them under MaterialApp as
routes (map<Sting, Function>) after you have to give parameter to initial route still under MaterialApp, now you can use these routes by using Navigator.pushNaned and Navigator.pop function.